# connect to mysql container from another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I'm trying to connect to a mysql container from within another container on the same network specified by a compose file.

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_USER=dummy_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
```

I'm not really sure what the connection parameters would be if I'm trying to connect to the mysql container from the php container.

Specifically, what are the host and port for the mysql container from *within* another container of the same docker-compose network?

I've tried host: mysql port: 3306, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 11):

You should link the containers. Add *ports* section to *mysql* container and *links* section to *php* container.

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_USER=dummy_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
```

With that configuration you'll be able to access *mysql* container from *php* with **mysql:3306**

A bit of documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#updating-containers

Answer (score -1):

You don't share port for mysql

add to your docker-compose.yml to mysql service:

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

UPD

try to set environments of your mysql container

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
MYSQL_USER: dev
MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp
```

and

```
$link = mysqli_connect("mysql", "dev", "123456", "myapp");
```

should works fine

Comment: This is incorrect for shared services on the same docker network. I'm not exposing the container to the host. I want to expose the container to another container on the same docker network.

Comment: @Confused see upd