# Not able to connect to Postgres container from another container

Tags: postgresql, docker, flyway

This question has been asked many times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065419/not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-database-from-golang-docker-container), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503586/not-able-to-connect-to-mysql-container-from-php-container) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738592/connect-to-mysql-container-from-another-container) but these solutions are not working for me.

I have created a Postgres and a AppServer container with this `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: '-A md5'
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgressql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  api:
    build: api
    container_name: api
    volumes:
      - ./database/migrations:/migrations
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

After running this, I can successfully do

```
docker exec -it db psql -U user mydb
```

and I connect to Postgres successfully. I can also successfully login into terminals of both containers with

```
docker exec -it api bash
docker exec -it db bash
```

from inside of bash of api I can ping db without any problem

However from my api container, I cannot establish a JDBC connection to the Postgres database.

```
api    | Flyway Community Edition 7.3.2 by Redgate
api    | ERROR: 
api    | Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/mydb) for user 'user': Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
api    | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
api    | SQL State  : 08001
api    | Error Code : 0
api    | Message    : Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
api    | 
api    | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
api    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Why am I getting connection refused when I can connect via psql? This is my flyway conf

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/mydb
flyway.user=user
flyway.password=password
flyway.locations=filesystem:/migrations
```

Edit:: So if I wait and then execute `flyway migrate` after some time from `docker exec -it api bash` everything works fine. I think what is happening above is that my `flyway migrate` command is running even before the database is ready.

Why is this happening? because I have specified dependency so my API container should start only when the database has fully started. but it seems that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the database container as a dependency doesn't guarantee that it will be **ready** before your other services/containers. It only guarantees that it will **start** before your other services.

One way to get around this is to implement a retry attempt(s) in your API application when failing to connect to your database during startup.

Here is a [link](https://medium.com/@krishnaregmi/wait-for-it-docker-compose-f0bac30f3357#:%7E:text=Docker-compose%20%E2%80%99s%20depends_on%20will%20run%20the%20containers%20in,situations%20it%E2%80%99s%20helpful%20to%20use%20a%20wait-for-it.%20https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to an article that uses a shell script to wait for a service to be ready.

IMO your application should be smart enough to retry a few times when it cannot establish a database connection. It will make it more robust anyways.

Comment: This doesn't actually describe how to solve the problem.  What changes should the asker make in their code or container environment?